# What is the optimal value of a quadratic program when there does not exist a solution?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

If I have a quadratic program of the form

$$\min \frac 12 x^T Q x - \langle b,x \rangle$$

and there does not exist a solution, then what is the optimal value?

My intuition tells me that it is negative infinity!  beause that's what would happen if the $Q$ matrix were indefinite.  But I cannot prove it to myself, even though intuitively this makes sense to me.  How would one go about proving that the optimal value must be $-\infty$?

Comment: What do you mean by 'there does not exist a solution'? That the problem is unbounded below?

Comment: yes, in otherwords the optimality conditions are not met.

Comment: If $x$ is not restricted and the problem is unbounded below, the value is $-\infty$.

Comment: @LinAlg  Problem is unbounded exactly means it is $- \infty$.

OP is asking assume objective function is bounded below, can we prove that problem has optimal solution.

Comment: If $Q$ is positive definite, then the quadratic is guaranteed to have a finite optimum; and if $Q$ has even one negative eigenvalue, it is guaranteed to be unbounded below. But it still can have a finite optimum even if $Q$ is positive semidefinite and singular. In that case, the boundedness depends on an additional relationship between $Q$ and $b$ as well.

Comment: In dimensions 1 and 2 answer is $- \infty$ (if $Q$ is symmetric nonzero matrix)

Comment: @Redshoes is right on.  I know intuitively what you guys are saying, but how do I prove this?  Thanks.  MichaelGrant, yes that makes sense, but I want to know how to prove it using optimality conditions, etc.  I know that $\nabla f =0=(Q+Q^T)x-b$ is the FONC for optimality, but that doesn't seem to tell me much for this.

Comment: $Q$ should be symmetric. Then the question boils down to studying whether the linear system $Q x = b$ has zero, one or infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @Michael Grant I think there's no need additional assumption beside PSD.  Please check my answer.

Comment: @Redshoes  What if $Q\succeq 0$ and $b^TQb =0? Then let $x=tb$, where $t\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If There does not exist a solution to $min h(x)$, then $h(x)$ must not be a coercive function. Which means Q must not be positive semi definite.  That means that there exists at least one negative eigenvalue, which means the problem is unbounded below.

Comment: consider $Q=0$ and $b\neq0$ to see that the point about psd and a negative eigenvalue ist not correct.

Answer (score 0):

If $Q$ is **not** positive semidifinite then problem is unbounded below (The direction which takes us to $- \infty$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the negative eigenvalue).

So lets think about the case where $Q$ is positive semidefinite. Then we have following theorem

Theorem:

$f$ has optimal solution if and only if $f$ has finite infimum value.

**Pf**:  Left to Right is trivial.

For Right to left look at 
"https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-253-convex-analysis-and-optimization-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT6_253S12_lec_comp.pdf"  page 77.

Comment: Your theorem is assuming the premise. What are the conditions under which $f$ has a finite infimum value? It is *not* sufficient for $Q$ to be positive semidefinite. What if $Q\succeq 0$ and $b^TQb =0$? Then let $x=tb$, where $t\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: In that case problem has either optimal solution or it is unbounded below. @MichaelGrant

Comment: Well yes. But which is it? And what are the conditions under which each occurs? Again, assume $Q$ is PSD. What _else_ do we need to know about $b$ and $Q$ to conclude whether or not the problem is bounded?

Comment: I dont think we have same perception of question. What I get from this question is that  "If the optimal solution does not exist what we can say about optimum value? "  I'm saying the only possibility is $ - \infty $. Situation is like Linear Programing. It would be great the boundedness of $f$ can be reformulate in terms of  relation between $Q , b$  but it is not necessarily to answer this question.  @MichaelGrant

Comment: I see your point!